# Can't delete my question

Tags: feature-request, support, deleted-questions

I want to delete my question because of next:

1. I'm not longer interesting in it
2. I didn't get any proper answer that can't be even upvoted. No one else didn't upvoted any of these answers. Most of them even don't answer this question.
3. It decrease my "accept rate".

But I can't delete id because of "there are too many answers". May be the rules for question deletion should be reviewed?

This is the question itself:
[Is it possible to call an instance method from a static constructor in WCF service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2423709/is-it-possible-to-call-an-instance-method-from-a-static-constructor-in-wcf-servic)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bear in mind, you are destroying other people's answers -- answers they submitted in good faith -- when you delete your question. That's why the deletion rules are in place.

That said, I understand what you mean, as all 4 answers refer to your pre-edit version of the question. I humbly submit that you erred in the way you asked the question, since every answerer misunderstood you. :)

Good idea to bring this up on meta, though -- that's what it's here for!

Comment: What is you just published the question and want to delete it and no answers have been posted?